# 24-hours period rolling totals SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

I want an SQL query to find all my customers that spent more than > $500 in a rolling period of 24 hours based on their IDs numbers in the month of Jan and Feb. Say example: if a customer bought stuff for **$100, $300, $50, $200**,  sale date/s resp **2024-02-13 11:23:23,2024-02-13 13:23:23,2024-02-13 20:23:23, 2024-02-14 06:23:23 **: such a customer should be part of my result because **sum_total = $650 ** and the rolling period based on date and time is within 24hours. But i don't know how to query for the rolling period.

```sql
select 
  customers_id, 
  customer_name, 
  products_id,
  sales_date, 
  payment_type,
  sum(sales_price) over(partition by customers_id order by sales_date rows between sales_date and sales_date row) as total_amount
from 
  transactions 
where 
  sales_date between '2023-01-01' and '2023-02-29'
  and 
  sales_date = dateadd(hh, -24, sales_date 
having sum(sales_price)>500
```

Comment: Show us some example rows please. We’re looking for a minimal reproducible example, so that SO participants can see what you see, run what you run.